# Only Secure cookies returning NULL via $.cookie in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, https

I see the list of cookies in my Chrome Dev Resource section. 
And I call my cookies via console  `$.cookie` or even `document.cookie` and all the cookies show up except two of the secure cookies?

Do you guys no why? I need the value of the cookie to pass to a web-service to authenticate user.

Below image shows the the cookies in resources. The first two cookies are the ones i can't seem to be able to call on the client side.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those cookies are `HTTP-only` you won't be able to retrieve them via javascript:

> This is precisely why HTTP-only cookies are an important addition to
>   standard cookie implementations. If a cookie were marked as HTTP-only,
>   then a malicious script wouldn’t be able to access that cookie via
>   document.cookie and therefore wouldn’t be able to steal your cookies.
>   When HTTP-only cookies are officially supported in all browsers, it
>   will become a valid third option. Right now, it’s a nice mitigation
>   technique but not a preventative one. [Source](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/12/cookies-and-security/)

Comment: i put a screenshot up? its secure but I dont know how to check if the cookie is http-only?

Comment: Both cookies have the "HTTP" column with a check mark, meaning they are  "HTTP-only".

Answer (score 0):

The cookies you are unable to retrieve in JavaScript may have the [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag set.

```
the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script
```